# Get values from dynamic naming variables using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am working on assessment project, so i view questions, each question with multiple answers. the answers of the questions named dynamically ,my problem is i don't know how to extract data from this dynamic named  variables here example of code:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<?php foreach($answers as $answer) { ?>
<input id="optionsVisa" type="radio" name="answer<?php echo $answer['question_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $answer['fraction']; ?>"/>  <?php echo $answer['answer']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Any Help ??

Comment: Show your code what you have tried for fetch data.

Comment: you want extract in javascript?

Comment: i want to extract answers from the form that is sent using POST method using php

Comment: You have only one question? Why you have written name="question_id[]" outside the foreach loop.

Comment: @RuchishParikh he didn't it's still inside the loop it's just outside php which is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem:

```
    foreach($question_id as $key=>$value){
    $answer = isset($_POST['answer_'.$value]) ? $_POST['answer_'.$value] : '';
    $query = "insert into
     ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use a submit and then you will have them in your `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables assuming you have made a form around your inputs

After the submit, values submitted using a form with POST method can be found in `$_POST` variable `echo $_POST['answer2'];`

Comment: User have not tagged javascript,jquery in question.

Comment: @RuchishParikh true, but it's likely that might be a solution, i edited my answer a bit though to name it second and suggest it's use

Comment: i need the answer with php

Comment: @hany Than a submit will do? and you can retrieve the values out of the $_POST variable (as you stated you are using POST to send it), as you would be able to with any other form. what is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: the number of questions is dynamic and so i get number of answers dynamic  the issue is how every time get values from this dynamic variables using post

Comment: the same way you made the questions? you're sending all the questions as a post variable as well. loop through that array and for each question retrieve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have created one sample code which will help you. First you need to change name which will same for all because we need to group for single selection of answer.

So here input type name is `name="optionsVisa"` and id will be dynamic `id="answer_<?php echo $answer['question_id'];?>"`.

Now we will get one selected answer in `optionVisa` array. Please check below code.

**Sample Code**

```
<?php
$answers = array(
    '0' => array('question_id' => '1', 'fraction' => '1', 'answer' => 'test answer 1'),
    '1' => array('question_id' => '2', 'fraction' => '2', 'answer' => 'test answer 2'),
    '2' => array('question_id' => '3', 'fraction' => '3', 'answer' => 'test answer 3')
);  
?>  

<form id="test" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="<?php echo 1; ?>" />
<?php 
    foreach($answers as $answer) { ?>
    <input name="optionsVisa" type="radio" id="answer_<?php echo $answer['question_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $answer['fraction']; ?>"/>  <?php echo $answer['answer']; ?>
<?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit_form>
</form>

<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Question Id = 1
Answer Id = 3

Question Id = 1
Answer Id = 3

Array
(
    [question] => 1
    [optionsVisa] => 3
    [submit] => submit_form
)
```

Comment: Hope this useful to you. @hany